# Why isn't count() working the way I expect in my code?

Tags: python, django

```
class FriendshipManager(models.Manager):    
       def are_friends(self, user1, user2):
            if self.filter(from_user=user1, to_user=user2).count() > 0:
                return True
            if self.filter(from_user=user2, to_user=user1).count() > 0:
                return True
            return False
```

and i found count()
so i try it,
but it runs wrong

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
print a.count()
```

or

```
a='ssada'
print a.count()
```

why my code run wrong,but the FriendshipManager can run ,thanks 
Please try to use the code, rather than text, because my English is not very good, thank you

Comment: It seems like people are completely ignoring TFM and are just asking random questions on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that you've mixed up two methods with the same name.

On a sequence in Python, `count()` works exactly has Dustin describes to "count the number of occurrences of the parameter in the sequence."

The code you're referencing however, is from a Django model.  There, calling `count()` on the filter object is an alias for the SQL grouping function `COUNT`, which sums up the number of matching rows.

In essence, the `count` in your initial example and the `count` in the two examples after that aren't the same method at all.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If this is your preferred answer, would you mind clicking the checkmark to mark it as so?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use `len(a)` rather than `a.count()` if you want to determine the length/size of the list.  `a.count()` actually requires an argument anyway.  It counts the number of occurrences of a value.  For example:

```
a = [2, 6, 2, 1, 5, 3, 9, 5]
print a.count(5) #should display 2 because there are two elements with a value of 5
print a.count(3) #should display 1 because there is only one element with a value of 3
```

Answer (score 3):

len is the correct one for that case.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> print len(a)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a right answer, but, try this instead of the Model Manager code which you have. No big changes as such ofcourse.

```
class FriendshipManager(models.Manager):    
   def are_friends(self, user1, user2):
        if self.filter(from_user=user1, to_user=user2).count() or self.filter(from_user=user2, to_user=user1).count():
            return True
        return False
```

If count() returns a value other than zero, it will always return True.